# How to define and use custom structure type?

Tags: data-structures, types, opc-ua

Say I would like to define type `Person` with "fields" `Name` and `Age` in terms of OPC-UA (it is trivial to define a node of any structure of ByteStream and serialize/deserialize data -- this is not what I am after). Also I would like to define variable node `person` of type `Person` and write to that node in one step. **How to do it?**

Please note: when I update `person` with such data `(Kevin, 47)`, `(Jane, 22)` client should get in subscription, or when reading the variable directly only those 2 pairs, not something like `(Kevin,22)`.

*I use OPC-UA .Net official stack, but I should be able to "translate" from any given framework.*

Answer (score 2):

With OPC UA what has been trying to achieve above is possible.. it is called information modeling..

It depends on OPC UA SDK(Framework) to SDK whether it is supported..

If the SDK supports the custom Object Types, Custom Variable types creation then, it can be created with the the help of simple nodeset XML file for creating custom types..

In your example you can create an Variable Type called Person and create an instance of the same. And you will be able to achieve push notifications as you described above as well..

Please find the below mentioned Nodeset XML Snippet for creating the custom Object Type Custom Variable and creating the instance of the same.

```html
<!-- Below XML logic will explain on how to create Custom Object Type and Custom Variable Type-->

<UAObjectType NodeId="ns=2;s=PersonType" BrowseName="2:PersonType">
  <DisplayName>PersonType</DisplayName>
  <Description>A Person Object Type</Description>
  <References>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=2;s=NameType</Reference>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=2;s=AgeType</Reference>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasSubtype" IsForward="false">i=58</Reference>
  </References>
</UAObjectType>

<UAVariableType NodeId="ns=2;s=AgeType" BrowseName="2:AgeType" DataType="Byte">
  <DisplayName>AgeType</DisplayName>
  <Description>A Age variable type. it is component of AgeType</Description>
  <References>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false" >ns=2;s=PersonType</Reference>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasSubtype" IsForward="false">i=63</Reference>
  </References>
</UAVariableType>

<UAVariableType NodeId="ns=2;s=NameType" BrowseName="2:NameType" DataType="LocalizedText">
  <DisplayName>NameType</DisplayName>
  <Description>A Name Variable type. it is component of NameType</Description>
  <References>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false" >ns=2;s=PersonType</Reference>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasSubtype" IsForward="false">i=63</Reference>
  </References>
</UAVariableType>

<!-- Below XML logic will explain on how to create instance of an object using above mentioned types-->
<!-- This will create a person1 object inside the Object folder -->

<UAObject NodeId="ns=2;s=Person1" BrowseName="2:Person1">
  <DisplayName>Person1</DisplayName>
  <References>
    <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes" IsForward="false">i=85</Reference>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=2;s=Name1</Reference>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=2;s=Age1</Reference>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=2;s=PersonType</Reference>
  </References>
</UAObject>

<UAVariable NodeId="ns=2;s=Age1" BrowseName="2:Age1" DataType="Byte">
  <DisplayName>Age1</DisplayName>
  <Description>A Age variable type. it is component of AgeType</Description>
  <References>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false" >ns=2;s=Person1</Reference>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=2;s=AgeType</Reference>
  </References>
  <Value>
    <Byte>10</Byte>
  </Value>
</UAVariable>

<UAVariable NodeId="ns=2;s=Name1" BrowseName="2:Name1" DataType="LocalizedText">
  <DisplayName>Name1</DisplayName>
  <Description>A Name Variable type. it is component of NameType</Description>
  <References>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false" >ns=2;s=Person1</Reference>
    <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=2;s=NameType</Reference>
  </References>
  <Value>
    <LocalizedText>
      <Locale>en</Locale>
      <Text>MyName</Text>
    </LocalizedText>
  </Value>
</UAVariable>
```

If The SDK supports the nodeset file parsing, then please put this snippet in the existing nodeset file and import. Or create a nodeset file and put this snippet and import in your server code.

This will easily create a object types and its instances.

I hope this helps.

Thank you.

Comment: Many thanks, I cannot test and translate it into code right now, but I will try as soon as possible. Your answer is very helpful for me, so once again thank you!