# Define custom ObjectTypes and VariableTypes by code (C#) in OPCUA

Tags: c#, opc-ua

Related to the answer in [How to define and use custom structure type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859809/how-to-define-and-use-custom-structure-type), in which the custom ObjectType and VariableType are created by XML.

Is there a way to do this by C# code?

Alternately, use a mixed way defining only the types in XML and then create instance by code?

Any example repositories?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is a good idea to generate ObjectTypes and VariableTypes with a code generator and then create instance nodes. Especially when using Companion Specifications or predefined information models.

There are different stacks for C# (⁣[1](https://github.com/iswunistuttgart/awesome-opcua#c-2)) and each of the stack can deal with the generation and the types in different ways. Here is an example of this best practice for the UA-.NET Stack: [Boiler Example](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples/blob/3c316b3f25817b1d53d8f5e9c89b170209316695/Workshop/Boiler/Server/BoilerNodeManager.cs#L147)

If you use an other Stack you need to have a look to the examples or docs.